# Hello Can any one please tell me where do i found hive data stored directory?

Tags: hive

Hello Can any one please tell me where do i found hive data stored directory when i check through http://localhost:50070/ it shows  user/hive/warehouse but i didn't find it in my ubantu system. Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

/user/hive/warehouse would the default location in HDFS (not on local disc). You can find out where exactly data of a specific table is located by using DESCRIBE:

```
DESCRIBE EXTENDED yourTable;
```

Then check at the bottom in the detailed table information there will be a location field giving you the URI.